# Execute shell command in Tomcat

Tags: java, security, shell, tomcat, command

So I have the following problem: I have a web service running inside a Tomcat7 server on Linux. The web service however has to execute some commands (mostly file operations such as copy and mount). Copy I've replaced with java.nio, but I don't think that there is a replacement for `mount`.

***So I'm trying to execute shell commands out of my Tomcat Java process. Unfortunately it doesn't execute my commands***. I've implemented the execution of shell commands in Java before. So my code should be correct:

```
Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mount -o loop -t iso9660 <myimage> <mymountpoint>");
pr.waitFor();
```

`<myimage>` and `<mymountpoint>` are absolute paths, so no issues there either.

- I've debugged my commands and they are working when executed on the console.
- I've tried sending other commands. Simple commands such as `id` and `pwd` are working!
- I've tried using `/bin/bash -c "<command>"`, which didn't work.
- I've tried executing a shell script, which executes the command, which didn't work.
- I've tried escaping the spaces in my command, which didn't work.

So I've digged even deeper and now I'm suspecting some Tomcat security policy (**Sandbox**?), which prevents me from executing the command. Since security is no issue for me (it's an internal system, completely isolated from the outside world), I've tried a hack, which became quite popular just recently:

```
System.setSecurityManager(null);
```

This didn't work either. I'm using Java7 and Tomcat7 on RHEL6. Tomcat7 is just extracted! I don't have any files in /etc/.. or any other folder than /opt/tomcat/, where I've extracted the zip from the Tomcat home page. I've searched the /opt/tomcat/conf folder for security settings, but all I could find was the file catalina.policy, where it didn't seem like I could set some security level for shell commands.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you executing the commands under the same account under which Tomcat is running?

Comment: Yes, Tomcat is running as root. If I execute `id` I'm root as well.

Comment: What happens when you execute it ? Do you see any exception in the Tomcat logs ? Or does it just hang ?

Comment: No exceptions. It just doesn't execute the command. It's all going text-book-standard except the commands not getting executed. I'm suspecting Tomcat to simply absorb the commands because of some security settings.

Comment: I cannot stress this enough do not EVER run as ROOT

Comment: It is an internal environment. This is pure infrastructure in-house and we're lacking a Linux pro, so why should I bother with permissions?

Comment: Ever hear of "insider threat" it isn't always the outside world trying to get you.  If I wanted information from that box ir to just be a jerk you have given me unfettered access.  Even government networks can be compromised from the inside so even if you are on one it is no excuse.  While you may not have a linux pro there are many on the linux.se and google.  Let me know if you have any security related questions as i am more than happy to help.

Comment: Everybody has access to the machine anyways.. and now leave me alone. I made it very clear, that security is no issue!

Comment: Can I have the IP address of that box by chance?

Comment: Sure, 10.0.25.70 ;-) Hope you see the light..

Comment: Sorry for being a dick about it, but I know what I'm doing. I agree, security is important and I would never expose a public server like that.. But for an internal server I rather save the time worrying about  perms.

Comment: I don't think you are being a dick about it.  I deal with people that are true dicks on a daily basis, you are a refreshing "nice" person.

Comment: the standard tomcat user has no shell. usually it's set to "/bin/false" for security reasons. what you can do is create a worker-thread-information row in a database from your servlet and then set up a cron-job that executes your shellscript or command when there is work to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's generally a bad idea to use the single-string form of `Runtime.exec`. A better option is to use `ProcessBuilder`, and split up the arguments yourself rather than relying on Java to split them for you (which it does very naïvely).

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/mount", "-o", "loop", /*...*/);
pb.redirectErrorStream(true); // equivalent of 2>&1
Process p = pb.start();
```

You say you're on RHEL so do you have selinux active? Check your logs and see if this is what's blocking you (I think it's audit.log you're looking for, it's been a few years since I've used selinux). If this does turn out to be the problem then you should probably ask on superuser or serverfault rather than SO...

Comment: I haven't tried ProcessBuilder. And it's executed a bit differently than Runtime.exec(..). So I hope this helps. The weird thing is, that it seems to have something to do with Tomcat, since I can run the same class with normal Java (not within a servlet container such as Tomcat) and it executes the command correctly.

Comment: Yey, the `ProcessBuilder` finally solved my problem. Thanks a lot! I especially like the `redirectErrorStream(true)`, which finally gives me ALL output. I previously had the problem with `Runtime.exec(..)`, that only some output came through.

Comment: Without `redirectErrorStream` you can still get all the output, but you need to read the process stdout and stderr separately.

Comment: You are ignoring the security implications.  The above answer is both dangerous and misinformed.

Answer (score 7):

A few things:

```
System.setSecurityManager(null);
```

you have just killed the security of your application.

> Yes, Tomcat is running as root. If I execute id I'm root as well.

Fix this immediately!

Now on to the question.  You shouldnt have Tomcat executing anything, you need to defer this to a separate process whether that be a shell script or another Java program.  This should also remove what (I hope) was a dependency on root running Tomcat.  It should be possible to perform this command as a non-privileged user that cannot log into the system normally.  You would do this by configuring `/etc/fstab` and supplying that same user the permissions to do this.  From a pure security POV the process that mounts should not be owned by the tomcat user.  Nor should the tomcat user ever be root.   So to recap:
1)  Stop running Tomcat as root
2) Create a separate process outside of the context of Tomcat to run this mount
3)  Create a tomcat user, this user should not be able to log into the system nor should it be a privileged user (admin,super user, etc)
4)  Create a process user, this user should be configured exactly as the tomcat user
5)  Edit `/etc/fstab` giving the process user the necessary permissions to mount correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that's the problem you are having, but I've seen issues when Runtime.exec() is used without reading the associated output buffers. You can find a detailed explanation and potential solutions [here](http://vyvaks.wordpress.com/2006/05/27/does-runtimeexec-hangs-in-java/). Reading the output and error streams can also help you figure out what's going on at the OS level when you run the command.

Comment: Yes, I'm already printing out the stream with a BufferedReader. Sadly this doesn't give me anything. It's just like something is blocking any command.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently had to do something like this from a Swing app.

You'll probably be able to pull it off with ProcessBuilder, as in Ian's answer, but I found that once things start to get complex, it's easier to write a shell script that does what you want, enabling you to pass as few parameters as possible. Then use ProcessBuilder to invoke the shell script.

If you're invoking anything that has more than really minimal output, you'll also have to read the output and error streams to keep the process from blocking when the output buffers fill, as it seems you are already doing.

Answer (score 1):

I use `sudo -S` before command and for the tomcat7 user: `tomcat7 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`

Comment: [Please format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)