# bash command from Grails application

Tags: shell, grails, groovy

I am working in grails application which needs to execute an external bash command like so:

```
def cmd= "example".execute()
cmd.waitFor()
```

the problem is that this command is well executed when i run it from development environment but when i deploy it into tomcat this command is not executed any more.

Can someone help me please to solve this problem?

Comment: Is your deployed machine the same as your development ? Can you run other commands on your deployed app using execute ?

Comment: btw, look at Ian Roberts solution in this post see if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533799/execute-shell-command-in-tomcat

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

It looks like you're invoking an Ant Task from your TaskService.

Without your code, or you adding more debugging, it will be difficult to help.

"On ne sait pas ce que fait TaskService, ajoute du debug dans le code, ca va etre dur d'aider sans détails"

---

Try to debug it, by putting this line right after your execute call.

```
cmd.text.eachLine { log.info it }
```

Comment: when i run the application it work without calling the external commande,  this is the result of debut: 2013-03-28 10:38:09,401 [31353833@qtp0-0] ERROR StackTrace  - Sanitizing stacktrace:
: exec returned: 2
 at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:636)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:662)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:487)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:105)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 at TaskService.invite(TaskService.groovy:26)